# too many arguments for function error but function clearly takes two arguments

Tags: c, function, arguments

code to ask user to input base and power and prints result:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    float v;
    int power;
    printf("Enter value of x:\t");
    scanf("%f", &v);
    printf("Enter power:\t");
    scanf("%d", &power);
    v = exp(v, power);
    printf("%.2f", v);
}

float exp(float n, int i) {
    float base = n;
    int power = i;
    float result = 1;
    while (power != 0)
    {
        result = result * base;
        --power;
    }
    return result;
}
```

compiler spits out:

```
x.c:11:6: error: too many arguments to function ‘exp’
   11 |  v = exp(v, power);
      |      ^~~
```

clearly:

```
float exp(float n, int i) {
```

takes two arguments. What's going on here?

Comment: There's a standard `exp()` function, that, even though you didn't include the correct header, your compiler is aware of and assumes you're using...

Comment: Another possible explanation: Need to declare the function before calling it. Otherwise compiler may make an implicit declaration which does not match the actual implementation.

Comment: That looks like an error message from gcc. When I compile your code with gcc (version 9.3.0), I get that error plus several warnings about the `exp` function. If you got those warnings, you should include them in your question.

Comment: Do not number your lines in code mark-up.  It makes it unnecessarily tedious for anyone to copy and paste your code to either use it in an answer or to compile it to reproduce the problem or test a solution.

Comment: What @KeithThompson says - warnings are usually indicative of semantic errors; you should address them _always_ and certainly before posting a question (unless the question is about the warning).  In this case they pretty much answer your question .

Answer (score 2):

It's because your exp function is not known by the compiler yet.

exp is built-in function in C.
The function prototype of exp() is: double exp(double x);

To make your program work, you should put your exp function above main function.

Comment: It's better to think up a different name (**and** then declare it before use). Standard library function names are reserved for use as names with external linkage; in other words, you can only use `exp` as a top-level name if it's `static`.

Comment: The function must be declared before the call *and* it should be called something other than `exp`.

Comment: *exp is built-in function in C* not really. `exp` is a standard library function declared in `<math.h>` and some environments have an implicit built-in definition for it.

Answer (score 2):

Two things are happening here.

1. You have not declared or defined `exp()` before use
2. Your compiler has a built-in for `exp()` with a different signature

I am not sure what compiler you are using but I would be surprised if there were not also warnings explaining this. GCC produces:

```
main.c: In function ‘main’:
main.c:12:11: warning: implicit declaration of function ‘exp’ [-Wimplicit-function-declaration]
       v = exp(v, power);                                                                                         
           ^~~
main.c:12:11: warning: incompatible implicit declaration of built-in function ‘exp’
main.c:12:11: note: include ‘’ or provide a declaration of ‘exp’
main.c:12:11: error: too many arguments to function ‘exp’
main.c: At top level:
main.c:18:9: warning: conflicting types for built-in function ‘exp’
   float exp(float n, int i) {                                                                                    
         ^~~
```

Providing a prototype solves the problem:

```
float exp(float n, int i) ;

int main()
{
    ...
}
```

However it is probably ill-advised.  The standard library function `exp()` computes *e* (Euler's number, 2.7182818...) raised to the given power the *single* argument, so is semantically different that your `exp()`.

Overriding a standard library function in this way is in any case ill advised even if it has the same semantics. I strongly suggest that you use a different name such as `power()` for example (not `pow()` - that is also a standard library function).